# What's the best way to restrict an environment to a specific CDN?

Tags: environments, cdn

We have had problems a couple times now where the links to the CDN in our components don't get properly updated between the team, QA, and staging environments.

Is there a way to force an error if the QA environment tries to access the team CDN or vice-versa? Or some other well-known solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the different CDNs are hosted at different IP addresses one possibility might be to configure the local `hosts` table for the machines in a certain environment in such way as to overwrite the DNS resolution for the CDNs which shouldn't be accessible and pointing them to either:

- a non-existent address, causing connection timeout failures if the invalid CDNs are referenced
- a server where the respective files cannot be found, causing 404 errors (faster than the connection timeouts)

Comment: clever, I like this.